# Is this an anti-pattern/code smell? - Using enum/class of consts to access class properties with [] instead of using dot property

Tags: properties, anti-patterns

```
class FruitFields {
  static const NAME = "name";
  static const DESCRIPTION = "descriptionText";
}

class Fruit {
final string name;
final string descriptionText;

Fruit(required string id, required string descriptionText);
}
```

Then when I want to do something with a Fruit use the [] instead of . notation.

```
var banana = new Fruit('banana', 'a yellow fruit')
banana[FruitFields.DESCRIPTION]  = 'a very yellow fruit'

// instead of 
banana.descriptionText = 'a very yellow fruit'
```

Why? So I can refactor without having to think. If I want to change DESCRIPTION to SUMMARY it's easier to do a find and replace on FruitFields.DESCRIPTION verse apple.descriptionText, banana.descriptionText... where some non fruit object like car.descriptiontText could have a similarly named property I would have to watch out for.

I can't tell if this dumb or not.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't help you to spot a typo in the value if you use strings. Using enums however, the compiler only let you use valid values. You also get an performance benefit. An enum value is just a number and it's faster to work with numbers than with strings.

Comment: So when I do this in javascript I do use a named Enum but in dart enums only have integer values which don't really work for the functionality I'm demonstrating. I mean I don't think its very readable to have an object with all of its property values as numbers instead of human readable names. Unless I'm misunderstanding you. As far as compiler goes when I type FruitFields I do get an auto suggest that ensures I don't type the wrong thing and it does highlight it if I do.